# Конкатенация значения к атрибуту элемента на jquery

Tags: jquery

Использую следующий код:

Разметка:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="human" value="1">
</div>
<div class="dropdown-menu fix">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="man" value="1" checked>
        <input type="radio" name="man" value="2">
        <input type="radio" name="man" value="3">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="child" value=" - 1">
        <input type="radio" name="child" value=" - 2">
        <input type="radio" name="child" value=" - 3">
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Задача стоит сделать автозаполнение формы по клику на чекбоксы 
и получить что-то такое:

```
<input type="text" id="human" value="A - B">
```

Где чекбоксы из первого fieldset будут менять значение A,
а чекбоксы из второго fieldset менять значение B (вместе с сепаратором).
Значение B является не обязательным и может быть проигнорировано или отменено при повторном клике на выбранный чекбокс.

Использую следующий код:

```
$(function() {
    $(".fix input[name='man']").click(function() {
        var i = $(this).attr("value");
        $(this).parents().find("input[name='child']").removeAttr("checked");
        $(this).parents().find("input[id='human']").attr("value", i);

    });
    $(".fix input[name='child']").click(function() {
        var i = $(this).attr("value");
        var old = $(this).parents().find("input[id='human']").attr("value");
        $(this).parents().find("input[id='human']").attr("value", old + i);

    })

});
```

Но при повтоном клике на вспомогательные чекбоксы к атрибуту value текстового поля бесконечно добавляется значение -B, а нужно чтобы оно изменялось.
Как можно модернизировать код, для правильной работы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var target = $('#human')
    , men = $('.fix input[name="man"]')
    , children = $('.fix input[name="child"]');
  children.click(function() {
    if ('on' === $(this).data('state')) {  
      $(this).data('state', 'off').removeAttr('checked');
    }
    else {
      children.data('state', 'off');
      $(this).data('state', 'on').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
  });
  men.add(children).click(function() {
    target.val((men.filter(':checked').val() || '')
      + (children.filter(':checked').val() || ''));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="human" value="1">
</div>
<div class="dropdown-menu fix">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="man" value="1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="man" value="2">
    <input type="radio" name="man" value="3">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="child" value=" - 1">
    <input type="radio" name="child" value=" - 2">
    <input type="radio" name="child" value=" - 3">
  </fieldset>
</div>
```